# How to make route in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have tried to make routes or links in angular
For example

I have default page

```
Localhost:4200
```

And it's brings the angular default page when I newly install Angular/CLI.
But how do I create my own personal page.
For Example

```
Localhost:4200/myPage
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you enable routing. You are given the option upon creation of your project. If you did not enable routing just use this command.

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

Next, you have to add routes to the app-routing.module file. You should declare an array of routes. These routes need to contain the path and the component to instantiate.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'mypage', component: MyPageComponent}
];
```

Next change the NgModule decorator to

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Now you should be able to navigate to the paths set with ease. I do agree with the earlier comment though, this is really something you should attempt with documentation first before asking here.